# How can I create an "ID" column in one dataframe based on the index of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes.  One data frame has four columns: 'Sample_Artists', 'Sample_Songs', 'Sampled_Songs' and 'Sampled_Artists'.  The other dataframe has two column: 'Artists' and 'Songs.  The second dataframe contains all the same artist and song names as the first, but the first dataframe contains relational data I would like to keep (in other words, all pairs of artists and songs contained in the first data frame are unique rows in the second data frame).

Essentially, I want to create two more columns in my first data frame that uses the index of my second data frame as an ID, such that for each unique Artist and Song pair, I have a matching index from my second data frame.

Here's a simple example of what I want to do:

Say I have

```
df = 
Sample_Artist Sample_Song Sampled_Artist Sampled_Song
A+            foo         B+             bar
A+            foobar      C+             barfoo
B+            5           A+             foobar
```

Then I have another dataframe

```
df1 = 
index  Artist Song
0      A+     foo
1      A+     foobar
2      B+     bar
3      B+     5
4      C+     barfoo
```

Now I want to add two columns to my first dataframe:

```
df = 
Sample_Artist Sample_Song Sampled_Artist Sampled_Song Sample_ID Sampled_ID
A+            foo         B+             bar          0         2
A+            foobar      C+             barfoo       1         4
B+            5           A+             foobar       3         0
```

This seems super straightforward, but I can't figure out where to start.  I did something similar to this with groupby, but couldn't get my indices to match with my second dataframe (df1 in the example).

Edit :

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO('''\
Sample_Artist Sample_Song Sampled_Artist Sampled_Song
A+            foo         B+             bar
A+            foobar      C+             barfoo
B+            5           A+             foobar
A+            foo         B+             5'''), sep='\s+')

df1 = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO('''\
Artist Song
A+     foo
A+     foobar
B+     bar
B+     5
C+     barfoo'''), sep='\s+')

df.index.names = ['Sample_ID']
df1.index.names = ['Sampled_ID']
df = df.reset_index()
df1 = df1.reset_index()
result = pd.merge(df, df1, left_on=['Sampled_Artist', 'Sampled_Song'],
     right_on=['Artist', 'Song'],
     how='left')

result = result[['Sample_Artist',
                 'Sample_Song',
                 'Sampled_Artist',
                 'Sampled_Song',
                 'Sample_ID',
                 'Sampled_ID']]


print(result)


  Sample_Artist Sample_Song Sampled_Artist Sampled_Song  Sample_ID  Sampled_ID
0            A+         foo             B+          bar          0           2
1            A+      foobar             C+       barfoo          1           4
2            B+           5             A+       foobar          2           1
3            A+         foo             B+            5          3           3
```

So your code gives me the Sample_ID and the Sampled_ID equal to 3 (index 3, when it should give Sample_ID = 0 and Sample_ID = 3).  The entire Sample_ID column is off (and Sampled_ID is good), but I can't figure out exactly why.

I'd like to see:

```
  Sample_Artist Sample_Song Sampled_Artist Sampled_Song  Sample_ID  Sampled_ID
0            A+         foo             B+          bar          0           2
1            A+      foobar             C+       barfoo          1           4
2            B+           5             A+       foobar          3           1
3            A+         foo             B+            5          0           3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO('''\
Sample_Artist Sample_Song Sampled_Artist Sampled_Song
A+            foo         B+             bar
A+            foobar      C+             barfoo
B+            5           A+             foobar
A+            foo         B+             5'''), sep='\s+')

df1 = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO('''\
Artist Song
A+     foo
A+     foobar
B+     bar
B+     5
C+     barfoo'''), sep='\s+')


df1.index.names = ['Sampled_ID']
df1 = df1.reset_index()

grouped = df.groupby(['Sample_Artist', 'Sample_Song'])
df['Sample_ID'] = grouped['Sample_Artist'].transform(
    lambda grp: grp.index.get_level_values(0)[0])

result = pd.merge(df, df1, left_on=['Sampled_Artist', 'Sampled_Song'],
     right_on=['Artist', 'Song'],
     how='left')

result = result[['Sample_Artist',
                 'Sample_Song',
                 'Sampled_Artist',
                 'Sampled_Song',
                 'Sample_ID',
                 'Sampled_ID']]


print(result)
```

yields

```
  Sample_Artist Sample_Song Sampled_Artist Sampled_Song Sample_ID  Sampled_ID
0            A+         foo             B+          bar         0           2
1            A+      foobar             C+       barfoo         1           4
2            B+           5             A+       foobar         2           1
3            A+         foo             B+            5         0           3
```

Comment: Thanks!  This seems to work for the right hand side (The sampled_id's), but if I have duplicates in the Sample_Artists, it assigns each duplicate a unique ID...  I see why this is: because you set left_on to the sampled version rather than the sample version... But I want both of them to be using the same IDs...

Comment: Can you update your post with some data which demonstrates the problem, and the desired result?

Comment: Yea.  Basically the sample_id column doesn't use the index data at all.  I updated my post to show the issue.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  Just do the merge twice, and make one of them based on the sample_id, one based on the sampled_id, and put one column into the other.

Comment: You could use `groupby/transform` to assign one unique `'Sample_ID'` to each `('Sample_Artist', 'Sample_Song')` group. I've edited the code above to show what I mean. I'm curious to know how you solved it. Would you please post your solution too?